# Click Event Listener for background image not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my image1 class. On clicking this I want to change the background image.

```
<li class="sidebar-element">
                    <div class="image1">
                        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                        <span>Image 1</span>
                        <hr>
                        <hr id="second">
                    </div>
                </li>
```

This is the Javascript code inside the same file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var image1 = document.querySelectorAll(".image1");
image1.addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundimage = "url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582392487150-b0bc00f92e28?ixlib=rb-                                   1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)";
        });
```

I've an original background image which I have defined in my css file.

```
body{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 300;
color: white;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
background: #222222;
background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582392487150-b0bc00f92e28?ixlib=rb-                                   1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
```

}

Comment: If you only have one image, use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` as `querySelectorAll` returns an array of all matching elements.

Comment: @imvain2 `.querySelectorAll()` actually returns an HTML Collection (node list), not an array.

Comment: I've changed that to querySelector but am still unable to change the background image. Let me know what else should I change or should I post more code. I also noticed that I had same url in both places and I changed that as well but still not getting a different background image.

Comment: `.style.backgroundimage` -> `.style.backgroundImage`

Comment: Tried that as well but not getting it. I've added javascript at the bottom of my original html code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting up the background with inline styles (which is generally considered the last resort because of how hard it is to override and because of how cluttered it makes the rendered HTML), do it with CSS classes and the [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API as shown below:

```js
document.querySelector(".image1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.classList.add("replacedBodyBackground");
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://www.doublemesh.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Paradise-Beach-desktop-wallpaper.jpg");
}

.replacedBodyBackground {
  background-image: url("https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/3872255-31-beach-backgrounds-psd-jpeg-png-free-premium-templates-beach-png-background-585_329_preview.webp");
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
   <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
   <span>Image 1</span>
   <hr>
   <hr id="second">
</div>
```

Comment: I had one more question actually which isn't too much related to code but around referencing. My main files (app.js, test.ejs and maintest.css) are placed like below:
MyProjects/website1/app.js
MyProjects/website1/views1/test.ejs
MyProjects/website1/views1/maintest.css
If I created an external JS file inside my views directory how will I able to reference it in my test.ejs file?

Just to let you know, I'm using GoormIDE which is a cloud programming tool.

Comment: @CuriousLearner I don't know anything about GormIDE, but [this](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/relative-and-absolute-urls) should help.

Answer (score 0):

when you select elements using querySelectorAll it returns an HTML Collection (node list) even if there is no element matches the selector, so to access it you should access it as an array element like this

```js
var image1 = document.querySelectorAll(".image1");
image1[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582392487150-b0bc00f92e28?ixlib=rb-                                   1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)";
        });
```

or you can use querySelector like this

```js
var image1 = document.querySelector(".image1");
image1.addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582392487150-b0bc00f92e28?ixlib=rb-                                   1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)";
        });
```

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` actually returns an HTML Collection (node list), not an array. And, it returns that even if no elements match the query - - it just returns an empty one.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: I'v changed that to querySelector but am still unable to change the background image. Let me know what else should I change or should I post more code. I also noticed that I had same url in both places and I changed that as well but still not getting a different background image.

Comment: use backgroundImage with capital I and not backgroundimage

Comment: Tried that as well but not getting it. I've added javascript at the bottom of my original html code.

Comment: Here check it in this pen https://codepen.io/am-77/pen/LYpgNze its working fine. @CuriousLearner

Comment: It seems to work on CodePen but it still didn't work in my code. Btw I'm using GoormIDE. Scott Marcus suggested adding a classList instead of using the document.body thing and it worked.

Comment: I had one more question actually which isn't too much related to code but around referencing. My main files (app.js, test.ejs and maintest.css) are placed like below: MyProjects/website1/app.js                                       
MyProjects/website1/views1/test.ejs              
MyProjects/website1/views1/maintest.css.                                                                       
If I created an external JS file inside my views directory how will I able to reference it in my test.ejs file? Just to let you know, I'm using GoormIDE which is a cloud programming tool.